# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

Does anyone has faced this problem with react-native-camera when taking a picture

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B52996FD-EBCD-4B8D-A289-81063B8F09E9&ext=JPG'
>   ?(edited)

Comment: Hey @alberto did you find any related solution? Thanks in advance,.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct directory when running the command.